# How do i push new Fragment onto tabFragment?

Tags: java, android, interface, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a tabbed app with four Fragments. To handle them i extend **FragmentPagerAdapter** and use a **FragmentManager**, *mFragmentManager*.
 In one of these Fragments i need to press a button and display another Fragment(but back should of course go back to the old one).

Now i tried using an interface where this method is called when the user presses that button:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 ......
switch(position){  
case 0: 
    if(mFragmentAtHome ==null)
    {
    mFragmentAtHome = HomeScreenFragment.newInstance(new HomeScreenFragmentListener()
    {
       public void onSwitchToCreateCity() {
       mFragmentOnHome = All_media.newInstance(aml);
       mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(mFragmentOnHome,"allMfrag").commit();
       notifyDataSetChanged();

       //Lets see what the manager looks like
       System.out.println("mFragmentManager:");
       System.out.println(mFragmentManager.getFragments().toString());
       }
      }); 

    }  
    return mFragmentAtHome;

case1:...
```

But somehow my fragment is not displayed. Still logcat tells me it is on the mFragmentManager:

```
 mFragmentManager:
[HomeScreenFragment{41798e80 #0 id=0x7f050028 android:switcher:2131034152:0},  
MyTripsFragment{4170d5d0 #1 id=0x7f050028 android:switcher:2131034152:1},   
All_media{418f5f50 #2 allMfrag}]
```

But it doesn't have an id, or a android:switcher something.

What can i do?

Thanks!